# App migrated to .net 4, NewRelic shows double requests and time in System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, iis, newrelic

We have just migrated an app from .Net 2 to .Net 4 (without major code changes); the app uses a custom HttpModule to serve extensionless URLs (based on a 404 page - request comes in, hits our custom 404 page, goes through the module and gets transferred to the correct page behind the scenes).

Everything is working well post-migration, but NewRelic is showing a very high number of requests per minute (we know it's not right, because we can monitor current requests on the firewall or load balancer) and showing a lot of time spent in /System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.

Has anyone seen this before? I suspect it could be ASP .Net trying to handle the extensionless URL for us, but I'm not sure how to prevent this - I'm just working to get an enviroment where I can do a bit of testing, but if anyone has any suggestions I'd love to hear them!

Thanks
Sam

Comment: There are many factors that could be contributing to this, so it would be best to contact support.newrelic.com so we can take a look at the details of your environment.

Comment: Thanks @lauradiane - it turned out that it was just a matter of removing the ASP .Net 4 extensionless URL handler via web.config, time went from 300ms to 25ms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this - it was just a matter of removing the ASP .Net 4 extensionless URL handler via web.config, as it was trying to also process the request at the same time as our 404 handler.